# Error when building a Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, lxc, device-mapper

The command docker build fails with error :

```
Error getting container f43128eda488c88a3b2e111aafb30b80a44faaead33bcf02f8bffd7ae1832753 from driver devicemapper: Error mounting '/dev/mapper/docker-8:2-41159178-f43128eda488c88a3b2e111aafb30b80a44faaead33bcf02f8bffd7ae1832753' on '/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/f43128eda488c88a3b2e111aafb30b80a44faaead33bcf02f8bffd7ae1832753': no such file or directory
```

docker info

```
Containers: 7
Images: 148
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:2-41159178-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 27.96 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 79.42 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 19.27 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.128 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.77 (2012-10-15)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.14.27-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.66 GiB
Name: libra
ID: KYU6:KECQ:GGF3:QL4W:SB35:C3UX:54EY:NN3A:U4RF:SFIK:5ULD:2THZ
Username: porfus
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

I use root-server OVH Kimsufi and Ubuntu 14.04.2 (3.14.27-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 14:02:42 CET 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux). I read the description of this bug on GitHub (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4036), but did not understand how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you have "Library Version: 1.02.77 (2012-10-15)", consider upgrading docker and that library to its latest version.

That would make sure all the fixes mentioned in [issues/4036](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4036) are taken into account.